# Cannot transfer files to the PC through Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

The Bluetooth starts by itself on login and when I try to transfer a file from my Android phone to it, it doesn't accept it. While "searching," my phone shows my PC but the file doesn't get accepted.

Comment: Phone manufacturer? Serivce provider?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Personal File sharing Preferences

and enable the options below  see image

[image]